# Maps between Equivalence Relations and Partitions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations, set-partition

**NOTE: [I’m not (yet) interested in proving that there is a bijection] ~ not a duplicate**

---

Consider the following definition.

> **Definition:** Let $A$ be a non-empty set. Let $\varepsilon(A)$ denote the set of all equivalence relations on $A$, and let $\mathcal{T}_{A}$ be the set of all partitions of $A$.
>
> Define a map $\Phi:\varepsilon(A) \to \mathcal{T}_{A}$ as follows. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, let $\Phi(\sim)$ be the quotient set $A/\sim$.
>
> Define the map $\Psi: \mathcal{T}_{A} \to \varepsilon(A)$ as follows. If $\mathcal{D}$ is a partition of $A$, let $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ be the relation on $A$ given by $x \Psi(\mathcal{D}) y$ if and only if ther is some $P \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $x, y \in P$, for all $x, y \in A$.

Then, consider the following lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $A$ be a non-empty set. The maps $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ in the above definition are well-defined.

**I want to prove this result.** Although I don’t know what I should do in order to show the *well-definition* of these maps.

**The problem:** Generally speaking, let $A, B$ be non-empty sets and let $f: A \to B$. To show that $f$ is well-defined we need to show:

1. that $x = y$ implies $f(x) = f(y)$ for all $x, y \in A$

**OR**

2. that $f(x) \in B$ for all $x \in A$.

**And how do I apply the correct strategy in the case of the maps $\Phi$ and $\Psi$?**

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: How are you defining the quotient set?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - Let $A$ be a set, and let ~ be an equivalence relation on $A$. The **quotient set** is the set $A/$~ $ = \{ [x] | x \in A \}$. In other words, it is the set of all the equivalence relations. Thank you for your attention

Comment: So how is the quotient set different than $\epsilon (A)$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField - Note that an element of $\varepsilon(A)$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, so it is a subset of $A \times A$, while the quotient set is not (by the definition above). It follows that they are in deed different

Comment: What does the notation $[x]$ mean then? What makes it different than $x$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: It’s the equivalence class of $x$: $$[x]=\{y\in A:x\sim y\}\,.$$

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of showing that
$\Phi(\mathord{\sim}) \in \mathcal{T}_A$ for all
$\mathord{\sim} \in \varepsilon(A),$ and
$\Psi(\mathcal{D}) \in \varepsilon(A)$ for all
$\mathcal{D} \in \mathcal{T}_A$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Right, but does he know that? Does he know what that means? It's obviously the partition he's looking for so I think that's the problem.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley that would be the option number $2$ in my question. But is there any difference between $1$ and $2$?

Comment: @CyclotomicField yes, I know that it’s the equivalence class of $x$. I know all the terms/definitions/objects that I am using in this question. My question is really about showing that these maps are well-defined. I want to know how to do that, I presented $2$ options, but I don’t know what is the correct one; after knowing the correct one, I would like to know (get a hint) of how to use it in the present problem. I hope this is more clear now. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Options 1 and 2 are indeed different. I can't see that option 1 even arises here. Its truth is implicit in the use of the symbol for equality. Something like option 1 *does* arise in two cases: (a) $f$ is only known to be a binary relation between $A$ and $B,$ and one has to show that $f$ is functional, i.e., if $z$ and $w$ are both related by $f$ to the same element of $A,$ then $z = w$; (b) $f$ is known to be a function from $A$ to $B,$ and equivalence relations are given on $A$ and $B,$ and one has to show that $f$ respects these relations. But I see no need to worry about (a) or (b) here.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Then it would suffice to show that $\Phi($~$)$ $\in \mathcal{T}_{A}$ and $\Psi(\mathcal{D}) \in \varepsilon(A)$, right?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can see, that's all that's required.

Comment: By the way, the $\sim$ character is produced (in $\LaTeX{}$ and MathJax) by `\sim`.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Thank you for the feedback I really appreciate! And for the $\sim$ thank you so much, I didn’t know that so it will be useful :)

Comment: You can probably now answer your own question. That would tidy everything up nicely.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley good suggestion! I’m going to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the maps $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are well-defined, it suffice to show that

1. for all equivalence relations $\sim$ on $A$, $\Phi(\sim)$ is a partition of $A$ (so $\Phi(A) \in \mathcal{T}_A$),
2. for all partitions $\mathcal{D}$ of $A$, $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ (so $\Psi(\mathcal{D}) \in \varepsilon(A)$).

---

*Proof:* By the definition of the map $\Phi$, we see that $\Phi(\sim)$ is the quotient set $A/\sim$, which is a partition of the set $A$. So this case is really straightforward.

Now, let $\mathcal{D}$ be a partition of the set $A$, and let $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ be a relation on $A$ such that, for all $x, y \in A$, $x \Psi(\mathcal{D}) y$ if and only if there exists some $P \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $x, y \in P$.

Let $a$ be any element of $A$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is a partition of $A$, we know that $\bigcup_{P \in \mathcal{D}} = A$. Hence $a \in \bigcup_{P \in \mathcal{D}}$. Therefore, there exists $P \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $x \in P$. Then $x \Psi(\mathcal{D}) x$. Therefore $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ is reflexive.

Let $b, c \in A$ such that $b \Psi(\mathcal{D}) c$. By definition, there exists a $P \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $b, c \in P$. It follows right from here, that $c \Psi(\mathcal{D}) b$. Therefore $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ is symmetric.

Let $d, e, f \in A$ such that $d \Psi(\mathcal{D}) e$ and $e \Psi(\mathcal{D}) f$. By definition there exists $P_1, P_2 \in \mathcal{D}$ such that $d,e \in P_1$ and $e,f \in P_2$. Note that $\mathcal{D}$ is a partition of $A$ and $P_1 \cap P_2 \neq \emptyset$. So $P_1 = P_2$. Then $x,z \in P_1=P_2$. So $d \Psi(\mathcal{D}) f$. Therefore $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ is transitive.

We conclude that $\Psi(\mathcal{D})$ is an equivalence relation on $A$, therefore it belongs to $\varepsilon(A)$.

This proves that these maps are both well-defined. $\square$

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Approve?

Comment: (+1) I approve.